# Getting adjusted closing price of stocks n R

Tags: r

I am trying to get adjusted closing price for stocks from Yahoo Finance.

Some data from the excel file, April2018.xlsx is as shown below with

```
dput(head(data,20)):

structure(list(Warrant.Code = c(11880, 12311, 13423, 13437, 14271, 
14704, 14770, 14812, 14924, 15285, 16189, 16575, 16584, 16595, 
16713, 16736, 16744, 17081, 17082, 17158), Warrant.Name = structure(c(14L, 
161L, 21L, 15L, 50L, 144L, 114L, 107L, 116L, 23L, 195L, 30L, 
76L, 150L, 45L, 131L, 91L, 18L, 41L, 179L), .Label = c("JP-AAC @EC1804A", 
"JP-AAC @EC1805C", "JP-AAC @EP1805A", "JP-AAC @EP1805B", "JP-ACMT@EC1804A", 
"JP-AGBK@EC1805A", "JP-AIA @EC1804A", "JP-AIA @EC1804C", "JP-AIA @EC1805A", 
"JP-AIA @EC1805B", "JP-AIA @EP1804B", "JP-BOCL@EC1804B", "JP-BOCL@EC1805A", 
"JP-BOCL@EC1805B", "JP-BOCL@EP1804A", "JP-BRIC@EC1805A", "JP-BYD @EC1804A", 
"JP-BYD @EC1804B", "JP-BYD @EC1805A", "JP-CCB @EC1804A", "JP-CCB @EC1805A", 
"JP-CGDN@EC1805A", "JP-CGHL@EC1805A", "JP-CGNP@EC1804A", "JP-CGS @EC1805A", 
"JP-CICC@EC1805A", "JP-CKA @EC1804A", "JP-CKH @EC1805A", "JP-CMB @EC1804A", 
"JP-CMB @EC1805A", "JP-CMB @EC1805B", "JP-CMBC@EC1805A", "JP-CMOB@EC1804A", 
"JP-CMOB@EC1804B", "JP-CMOB@EC1804C", "JP-CMOB@EC1805B", "JP-CMOB@EP1805A", 
"JP-CNBM@EC1805A", "JP-COVS@EC1805A", "JP-CRCC@EC1805A", "JP-CSCH@EC1804A", 
"JP-CTEL@EC1804A", "JP-CTEL@EC1805A", "JP-CTIH@EC1805A", "JP-GAC @EC1804A", 
"JP-GEG @EC1804A", "JP-GEG @EC1804B", "JP-GEG @EC1805B", "JP-GEG @EP1805A", 
"JP-GR&F@EC1805A", "JP-GWMC@EC1804A", "JP-HKEX@EC1804A", "JP-HKEX@EC1805B", 
"JP-HKEX@EC1805D", "JP-HKEX@EC1805E", "JP-HKEX@EP1805A", "JP-HKEX@EP1805C", 
"JP-HSBC@EC1804A", "JP-HSBC@EC1804B", "JP-HSBC@EC1804C", "JP-HSBC@EC1804D", 
"JP-HSBC@EC1805A", "JP-HSBC@EC1805B", "JP-HSCI@EC1805A", "JP-HTSE@EC1804A", 
"JP-HTSE@EC1805A", "JP-HUAP@EC1804A", "JP-ICBC@EC1804B", "JP-ICBC@EC1805A", 
"JP-ICBC@EP1804A", "JP-ICBC@EP1805B", "JP-IGG @EC1804A", "JP-IGG @EC1804B", 
"JP-IGG @EC1805A", "JP-KECL@EC1805A", "JP-L&F @EC1805A", "JP-MI&S@EC1805A", 
"JP-NCI @EC1804A", "JP-NWD @EC1804A", "JP-NWD @EC1804B", "JP-POLY@EC1805A", 
"JP-PSBC@EC1804A", "JP-SHEC@EC1805A", "JP-SHKP@EC1804A", "JP-SHKP@EC1805A", 
"JP-SHKP@EP1804B", "JP-SJM @EC1804A", "JP-SJM @EC1805A", "JP-SMIC@EC1804A", 
"JP-SMIC@EC1805A", "JP-WYNN@EC1805A", "JP-ZTE @EC1804A", "JP-ZTE @EC1804B", 
"JPAMCS3@EC1804A", "JPAMCS3@EC1804B", "JPANGAN@EC1805A", "JPASMPT@EC1804A", 
"JPBOCHK@EC1804B", "JPBOCHK@EC1805A", "JPBOCHK@EP1804A", "JPBYDEI@EC1804A", 
"JPBYDEI@EC1805A", "JPCEAIR@EC1804A", "JPCINDA@EC1804A", "JPCITBK@EC1805A", 
"JPCKINF@EC1804A", "JPCLIFE@EC1804A", "JPCLIFE@EC1804B", "JPCLIFE@EC1805A", 
"JPCLIFE@EC1805B", "JPCMOLY@EC1804A", "JPCMOLY@EC1805A", "JPCNOOC@EC1804B", 
"JPCNOOC@EC1805A", "JPCNOOC@EP1804A", "JPCNOOC@EP1805B", "JPCP&CC@EC1805A", 
"JPCP&CC@EC1805B", "JPCP&CC@EC1805C", "JPCSA50@EC1804A", "JPCSA50@EC1805A", 
"JPCSA50@EC1805B", "JPCSHCL@EC1804A", "JPCSHCL@EC1805A", "JPCSHEN@EC1804A", 
"JPFOSUN@EC1804A", "JPFOSUN@EC1804B", "JPFTA50@EC1804A", "JPFTA50@EC1805A", 
"JPGEELY@EC1804A", "JPGEELY@EC1804C", "JPGEELY@EC1804E", "JPGEELY@EC1804G", 
"JPGEELY@EC1805A", "JPGEELY@EC1805B", "JPGEELY@EP1804B", "JPGEELY@EP1804D", 
"JPGEELY@EP1804F", "JPGFSEC@EC1804A", "JPGJINT@EC1804A", "JPHLAND@EC1804A", 
"JPHLAND@EC1805A", "JPKINGB@EC1804A", "JPKINGB@EC1805A", "JPKINGB@EC1805B", 
"JPKINGD@EC1805A", "JPKSOFT@EC1804A", "JPKSOFT@EC1805A", "JPLENOV@EC1804A", 
"JPLFPPT@EC1804A", "JPLFPPT@EC1805A", "JPLININ@EC1804A", "JPMEITU@EC1805A", 
"JPMELCO@EC1804A", "JPNDPHL@EC1804A", "JPPETCH@EC1805A", "JPPETCH@EC1805B", 
"JPPICCG@EC1805A", "JPPINAN@EC1804A", "JPPINAN@EC1804C", "JPPINAN@EC1805A", 
"JPPINAN@EC1805B", "JPPINAN@EC1805C", "JPPINAN@EC1805D", "JPPINAN@EC1805E", 
"JPPINAN@EC1805H", "JPPINAN@EC1805I", "JPPINAN@EP1804B", "JPPINAN@EP1805F", 
"JPPINAN@EP1805G", "JPSANDS@EC1804A", "JPSANDS@EC1805A", "JPSPDRG@EC1804A", 
"JPSUNAC@EC1804A", "JPTENCT@EC1804A", "JPTENCT@EC1804C", "JPTENCT@EC1804D", 
"JPTENCT@EC1804E", "JPTENCT@EC1804F", "JPTENCT@EC1805A", "JPTENCT@EC1805B", 
"JPTENCT@EC1805C", "JPTENCT@EC1805D", "JPTENCT@EC1805F", "JPTENCT@EC1805G", 
"JPTENCT@EC1805H", "JPTENCT@EC1805I", "JPTENCT@EC1805K", "JPTENCT@EC1805L", 
"JPTENCT@EP1804B", "JPTENCT@EP1804G", "JPTENCT@EP1805E", "JPTENCT@EP1805J", 
"JPVANKE@EC1804A", "JPVANKE@EC1805A", "JPWANWA@EC1805A", "JPZHJIN@EC1805A"
), class = "factor"), Trade.Date = structure(c(17651, 17651, 
17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 
17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651
), class = "Date"), Issuer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "JP", class = "factor"), 
    Underlying = c(3988, 2318, 939, 3988, 2777, 148, 883, 2628, 
    883, 384, 2202, 3968, 494, 960, 2238, 175, 1128, 1211, 1668, 
    700), Call.Put = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Call", 
    "Put"), class = "factor"), Maturity.Date = structure(c(17682, 
    17681, 17653, 17651, 17682, 17654, 17682, 17651, 17665, 17653, 
    17653, 17669, 17653, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17653, 17651, 17651, 
    17651), class = "Date"), Strike.Currency = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "HKD", class = "factor"), Strike = c(4.68, 
    69.69, 8.08, 3.83, 22.22, 48.48, 10.88, 28, 10.36, 25.52, 
    34.34, 32.88, 4.84, 26.62, 22.3, 19.19, 24.319, 90.9, 2.52, 
    408.18)), .Names = c("Warrant.Code", "Warrant.Name", "Trade.Date", 
"Issuer", "Underlying", "Call.Put", "Maturity.Date", "Strike.Currency", 
"Strike"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below is my code:

```
install.packages("quantmod")
install.packages("xlsx")
library(quantmod)
library(xlsx)

data=read.xlsx("C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/April2018.xlsx",sheetName="April2018")

dput(head(data,20))

data[,5]=paste(data[,5],".HK",sep="")

getSymbols(data[1,5],from=data[,7],to=data[,7],src="yahoo")

price=Ad(cat("`",getSymbols(data[1,5],from=data[,7],to=data[,7],src="yahoo"),"`",sep=""))
```

What I want is the code as below so that I do not have to manually type stock quote:

```
price=Ad(`3988.HK`)
```

However, I am not sure why it is not working for

```
price=Ad(cat("`",getSymbols(data[1,5],from=data[,7],to=data[,7],src="yahoo"),"`",sep=""))
```

The error is :
Error in Ad(cat("`", getSymbols(data[1, 5], from = data[, 7], to = data[,  : 
  subscript out of bounds: no column name containing "Adjusted"

Comment: @Hack-R Hi, do you know how to solve my problem? Thank you!

Comment: Try `paste`, not `cat`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hi I tried paste too, but it showed Error in Ad(paste("`", getSymbols(data[1, 5], from = data[, 7], to = data[,  : 
  subscript out of bounds: no column name containing "Adjusted". Do you know why?

Comment: @Hack-R Hi, I am new to the site. Can help me please? I will follow the instructions when I understand what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question with the output of `dput(data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`. This is what @Hack-R meant when he said that screenshots are not for showing tabular data.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I edited, can help pls? thx

Comment: @Hack-R can help please? thx

Comment: Thanks for your improvements. I've added an answer below and upvoted your question. Please check it out and if it fixes your problem then you can mark it as solved with the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in your use of `Ad()`.

The error is because internally it ran `has.Ad()` and got a TRUE result.

In this context it's because you've misunderstood how to specify the input for that command. After you run `getSymbols` you've `attach()`-ed an `xts` object of the same name, then you run `Ad()` directly on it, i.e.

```
getSymbols('IBM',src='yahoo')
Ad(IBM)
```

or, in your case, something like this:

```
getSymbols(data[1,5],from=data[,7],to=data[,7],src="yahoo")
# "3988.HK"
# Apparently that also loads an xts() with attach(), even tho that's a 
#   really bad practice
str(`3988.HK`)
```

> ```
> An ‘xts’ object on 2018-05-31/2018-05-31 containing:
>   Data: num [1, 1:6] 4.11 4.13 4.07 4.10 4.85e+08 ...
>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>   ..$ : NULL
>   ..$ : chr [1:6] "3988.HK.Open" "3988.HK.High" "3988.HK.Low" "3988.HK.Close" ...
>   Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
>   xts Attributes:  
> List of 2
>  $ src    : chr "yahoo"
>  $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2018-07-01 14:51:15"
> ```

```
 Ad(`3988.HK`)
```

> ```
>            3988.HK.Adjusted
> 2018-05-31              4.1
> ```

will work just fine.